# React Native material top tab navigator: how to make text equally spaced?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator, react-native-tabnavigator, react-navigation-top-tabs

I'm using `"@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.1.7"` in my React Native app, and have the following top tab navigator:

[image]

The individual tabs are equal width, but each word is a different length, which means that there's unequal space between each word. I want to make it so that there is equal spacing around each word. Here is my code that I'm using for the navigator. The `style` property in `tabBarOptions` is the parent container with the red border, and the `tabStyle` property is the child containers with the yellow borders:

```
const CallsRequestsNavigatorOuter = () => createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
    {
        'Waiting': {screen: Waiting},
        'Active': {screen: Active},
        'Cleared': {screen: Cleared},
        'All': {screen: All},
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: "All",
        tabBarOptions: {
            style: {
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                borderTopWidth: 0,
                width: Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').width) - 100,
                left: 50,
                right: 0,
                shadowOpacity: 0,
                elevation: 0,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: 'red'
            },
            upperCaseLabel: false,
            tabStyle: {
                padding: 0,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                height: 0.45*topSwooshAspectRatio*Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').width),
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: 'yellow',
            },
            labelStyle: {
                fontSize: normalizeFontSize(13)
            },
            indicatorStyle: {
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            },
            activeTintColor: Color.lightBlueOpaque,
            inactiveTintColor: 'white'
        }
    }
)
```

SOLVED: add `contentContainerStyle: {alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-around'}` to `tabBarOptions`, and add `width: 'auto'` to `tabStyle`. The key is that `contentContainerStyle` rather than `style` is the direct parent of `tabStyle`. So now I have this:

[image]